# How to maximize $a%b$ by multiplying it with any non-negative integer?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, optimization

What is the maximum value we can attain for the following function? Maximum is obtained at which n?

> $f(a,b)=(n*a) mod (b) $
>   n is any natural number and we can vary it to maximize the function.
>   a and b are fixed

What is intuition behind solving such problems?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ fixed?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yes

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $b\ge 1$, then you can show as an exercise that $na$ takes on all values in $\{0,1,\ldots,b-1\}$ as $n$ varies through the integers. So you can get $na\equiv b-1\pmod{b}$ (largest possible value), which you can obtain by taking $n=(b-1)a^{-1}$, where $a^{-1}$ refers to the inverse of $a$ modulo $b$ (this inverse exists if and only if $a$ and $b$ are coprime).

Comment: The maximum value is $b-\gcd(a,b)$. There is no intuition – there is a theorem, and it states that the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$ is generated by their gcd. After that, it's easy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what is name of theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure it has a name. In a more general context, it's called Bezout's Theorem. It's also the theorem that proves the integers form a principal ideal domain. But at a much more elementary level, you'll find it in the opening chapters of any introductory Number Theory text, usually as a step along the road to the Unique Factorization Theorem.